# Django - 'UserViewPermissionClass' object has no attribute 'authenticate' with custom permissions

Tags: python, django, class, permissions, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to use custom permissions in my class based views.
When I try to run one of my views, I get a WrappedAttributeError : `'UserViewPermissionClass' object has no attribute 'authenticate'`

Here are my custom permissions :

```
class UserViewPermissionClass(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return request.user.is_admin
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            return True
        # default logic

class UserView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = ( UserViewPermissionClass,)
```

This is the class based view that I'm trying to run :

```
class HandleUsers(UserView):

    def get(self, request):
        """Only for admin"""
        try:
            users = User.objects.all()
        except User.DoesNotExist():
            return HttpResponse(status=404)
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        """For everyone"""
        serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.error)
```

Here are my settings for rest framework :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],
}
```

After doing some research I saw that my error could be due to my DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES. However I cannot see what could be blocking.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `authentication_classes=(UserViewPermissionClass,)` to `permission_classes=(UserViewPermissionClass,)`